# C++ Classes + objects and user interract

Tags: c++, class, object, user-interaction

i am new to c++ and i have a really bad time with classes and objects. I can't find a way to make the user to enter the data and not just some cout <<".."; from me. I need to understand classes and objects . I would really appreciate your help. I searched the forum for a similar question and i didn't find something, if i missed it i am really sorry .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ManosClass{
public:
    string name;
};

int main ()
{
    ManosClass co;
    co.name =          //i want here the user to enter his name for example and i can't figure a way to do this
    cout << co.name;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read user input, you are looking for see [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) or use `std::cin`

```
std::getline(std::cin, co.name);
```

or

```
std::cin >> co.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

`cout` sends things out. `cin` sends things in.
This might help:

```
cin >> co.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

cout is output . cin is used for input.

```
 cin >> co.name
```

enter the value into co.name

Comment: thank you also ! but i have a problem, why when i enter two words or more the result is only the first word but with this command std::getline(std::cin, co.name); i don't face this problem

Comment: getline works differently. 
check this link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Answer (score 1):

Consider the version of `getline()` which resides in `<string>` if you don't want to assume that a person's name is white space separated. Some names do contain more than one "word". Its also less clumsy than `cin.getline()` since you don't need to specify in advance the maximum length of someone's name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string strName;
   getline(cin, strName); //Will read up until enter is pressed
   //cin >> strName //will only return the first white space separated token
   //Do whatever you want with strName.
}
```

**Edit: Modified for to use original classes**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ManosClass{
public:
    string name; //You might want to look at rather not using public data in a class
};

int main ()
{
    ManosClass co;
    getline(cin, co.name);
    cout << co.name;
    return 0;
}
```

**Alternative: Operator overloading**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ManosClass{
public:
     friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const ManosClass& o);
     friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, ManosClass& o);
private:
    string name; //Hidden from prying eyes
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const ManosClass& o)
{
    out << o.name;
    return out;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& in, ManosClass& o)
{
    getline(in, o.name);
    return in;
}

int main ()
{
    ManosClass co;
    cin >> co; //Now co can be used with the stream operators
    cout << co;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it works, but correct me please if i am wrong, this is not a class

Comment: thank you ! i know i have to learn to use private classes.. thank you so much! i have to make it clear how to work with private classes..its really confusing